# How can I check if the for loop cannot be parallelize?

Tags: c, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp, hpc

I'm trying to parallelize these 3 `for`-loops. I think there are no dependencies, and they can be parallelized.
I applied the ***#pragma omp parallel for*** but it didn't work. The time is even slower.

Am I wrong and do these `for`-loops have some dependencies?

```c
for (I = 0; I < M; I++)
    for (J = 0; J < N; J++) {
        CU[I + 1][J] = .5 * (P[I + 1][J] + P[I][J]) * U[I + 1][J];

        CV[I][J + 1] = .5 * (P[I][J + 1] + P[I][J]) * V[I][J + 1];

        Z[I + 1][J + 1] =
            (FSDX * (V[I + 1][J + 1] - V[I][J + 1]) -
             FSDY * (U[I + 1][J + 1] - U[I + 1][J])) /
            (P[I][J] + P[I + 1][J] + P[I + 1][J + 1] + P[I][J + 1]);

        H[I][J] =
            P[I][J] + .25 * (U[I + 1][J] * U[I + 1][J] + U[I][J] * U[I][J] +
                             V[I][J + 1] * V[I][J + 1] + V[I][J] * V[I][J]);
    }

for (J = 0; J < N; J++) {
    CU[0][J] = CU[M][J];
    CV[M][J + 1] = CV[0][J + 1];
    Z[0][J + 1] = Z[M][J + 1];
    H[M][J] = H[0][J];
}

for (I = 0; I < M; I++) {
    CU[I + 1][N] = CU[I + 1][0];
    CV[I][0] = CV[I][N];
    Z[I + 1][0] = Z[I + 1][N];
    H[I][N] = H[I][0];
}
```

Comment: What are the values for M and N? Small matrices won't really benefit from parallelization. Also, this is something that looks like the perfect use case for `#pragma omp simd`.

Comment: All three of those loops seem to be both reading and writing to the arrays `CU`, `CV`, `Z` and `H` — it is hard to see how they aren't interacting with each other.  You've got a lot of explaining to do to justify that they are parallelizable.  I'm not an expert on the topic (I've never yet written `#pragma omp`), but …

Comment: @JonathanLeffler seem to me like you can easily parallelize the loops if you split the ranges equally among different threads, after all, those output arrays are all independent.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli — I said I'm not the expert.  You're probably proving it.  The OP hasn't explained why they think the loops are parallelizable.

Comment: A brief look tells me that each inner iteration 1. writes a unique element of each LHS array 2. does not use a LHS array in a RHS. So it's parallelizable. BUT! That's only about correctness. It says nothing about performance.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Incorrect result or longer runtime? 1) Regarding incorrect result: do not forget to use `private(J)` clause in the first case. If you do not use this variable after the loop it is much better to define it inside the `for` loop. 2) Runtime: parallelization has overhead. If `M` and `N` are small, the overheads are bigger than the gain by parallelization.